# Variables de entorno obtenidas mediante imagen docker se encuentran "undefined" al ser usadas en appModule - Angular

Tags: angular, docker, webpack

Estoy realizando una implementacion con webpack para recibir variables de entorno que se encuentren definidas en mi imagen de docker, misma donde posteriormente estara empaquetado mi proyecto de angular. Para llevar a cabo esta tarea realize la siguiente implementacion con **@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser** como builder. https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/using-os-environment-variables-in-angular-with-docker/

Todo funciona a la perfeccion ya que en mi appComponent realize un console.log(this.environments) y en este punto ya he logrado recibir mis variables, pero me encuentro con un problema en especifico ya que el lugar en donde requiero usar mis variables de entorno son en @AppModule. ¿Por que en este punto? Estoy usando una API REST que se encarga de realizar todas mis solicitudes https y debo injectarle la configuracion mediante un metodo forRoot:

[image: Configuracion API @AppModule]

Al intentar utilizar la variable en este punto obtengo un "undefined" por lo tanto mis servicios quedan totalmente inaccesibles.

La definicion de mis variables de entorno la hago de esta manera al generar la imagen Docker.

[image: DOCKER IMAGE]

Agradezco cualquier aporte que me ayude a solucionar mi inconveniente !

Comment: Estás haciendo el *deploy* en producción (*--prod*). ¿Tus dos `environment` de producción también tiene esas propiedades o sólo has rellenado el `environment` de desarrollo?

Comment: Estoy haciendo la compilacion de mi proyecto angular desde mi docker, y en este le estoy agregando el flag de produccion. En mi environment de desarrollo tengo las variables quemadas, por lo tanto si se estuvieran usando las de desarrollo estaria funcionando correctamente.

Comment: A eso voy, ¿también están las variables en el `environment` de producción?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el valor de las variables que declaras en el Dockerfile solo estan disponibles en el momento del build.
Para obtener variables en el contenedor debes declararlas al momento de correr el comando, ejemplo:

```
docker run -e "host=example.com" -e "puerto=443" -e "path=mypath" -e "protocol=https" node
```

Adicionalmente, docker ofrece la posibilidad de pasarle el valor que tenían las variables de entorno al momento de realizar el build, es decir, las declaradas en el **Dockerfile**, solo con declararlas por su nombre al momento de correr el container, ejemplo:

```
docker run -e host -e puerto -e path -e protocol node
```